# Clean URLs - How do I accomplish this?

Tags: php, javascript, html

My supervisor recently told me that instead of generating a page with something like this `$pagecontent = "<html><body>blahblahlbahblah</body></html>"`, it was better to have a page pull information from the database, and use a clean URL.

How does one go about using clean URLs? I've never done this before, and Google seems to have multiple different answers, and nothing clear cut. Is it a PHP thing? An HTML thing? A Javascript thing?

Comment: Can you give information about your setup? What webserver are you using? What software is running on it? etc.

Comment: You will probably want to ask your supervisor what he means by "Clean URLs" for this is not a defined pattern or what so ever.

Answer (score 2):

It's usually an .htaccess thing, called mod_rewrite, if you're using website is hosted under Apache (which, using PHP, most are). A quick example of a .htaccess file would be:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.feed|\.pdf|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?query=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

So, in this example, http://example.com/aLink/?test=a would be redirected to http://example.com/index.php?query=aLink/&test=a.

You can then use PHP to parse the `$_GET['query']` variable.

Answer (score 1):

Clean URLs are typically accomplished using URL rewrites, where they turn `site.com?var=1&var2=2` into `site.com/1/2`

On the Apache server, this is accomplished using mod_rewrite. You can experiment using Wordpress, which will generate the proper Apache files and code for rewriting Wordpress stuff like `?page=name&category=that` to `/name`.

Comment: More commonly site.com?var=1&var2=2 into site.com/var/1/var2/2 because otherwise you will be looking into some kind of routing system which requires predefined routes.

Answer (score 0):

I think what he meant is that instead of

```
http://www.snoop.com/pages?id=3
```

you'd rather have

```
http://www.snoop.com/pages/snoop_is_the_best
```

As mentioned in the comment, depending upon the webserver, webapp setup, you could get it for free. Apache uses `mod_rewrite` for e.g.

Answer (score 0):

With Apache and PHP, you can accomplish this without mod_rewrite as well. No one seems to care these days about the overhead needed to run mod_rewrite, but if you're interested in squeezing every bit of performance out of your web server, you might like the alternative method.

See `http://www.evolt.org/Making_clean_URLs_with_Apache_and_PHP` for an explanation of the solution using Apache's ForceType directive.

Answer (score 0):

A clean URL is just a URL without a query string. So for example, instead of `http://example.com/index.php?page=foo` you might want `http://example.com/foo`
They can become very complicated for large existing sites that want to move to clean URLs. As [Matt H](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1001866/matt-h) and others said, you can use Apache rewrite to change existing URLs into clean URLs. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html has the full documentation on mod_rewrite, but you'll probably learn faster from examples.  [jValdron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1058466/jvaldron) just posted a decent one.  And this answer is quickly becoming a mishmash of faster answers.  There is so much documentation for rewrites and handling them with PHP that a question this broad isn't really worth answering again.

**If you have a very large site** with a lot of php pages that take query strings, you're going to have to plan on either writing a ton of rewrites and making sure your links don't break or a single rewrite to a script that will handle redirecting to the right pages.

**If you are making a new site**, I'd go with rewriting your URLs to a single script that will get the content according to the URL.

Here is a famous example from Drupal's .htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
# Rewrite URLs of the form 'x' to the form 'index.php?q=x'.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Then `QSA` means query string append and the `L` before it means Last `Stop the rewriting process immediately and don't apply any more rules.`

Then index.php can access the URL with $_GET['q'].